# Execution Flow of Child and Parent

Tags: c, memory-management, binary, gdb, posix

After reading on the web that i can't really determine which process runs before i.e `child or parent` I planned to disable the ASLR on my PC and run debugger to see if i can generate the pattern of execution, the observations I made are below with a GitGist to the GDB disas (full) along with the source code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
fork();
//fork();
printf("LINUX\n");
//printf("my pid is %d",(int) getpid());
fork();
printf("REDHAT\n");
//printf("my pid is %d",(int) getpid());

//fork();
return 0;
}
```

this is the code i am talking about when i disas it in gdb it gave me:-

```
gdb-peda$ disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000000068a <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000000000000068b <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000000068e <+4>: call   0x560 <fork@plt>
   0x0000000000000693 <+9>: lea    rdi,[rip+0xaa]        # 0x744
   0x000000000000069a <+16>:    call   0x550 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000000069f <+21>:    call   0x560 <fork@plt>
   0x00000000000006a4 <+26>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0x9f]        # 0x74a
   0x00000000000006ab <+33>:    call   0x550 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000000006b0 <+38>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000000006b5 <+43>:    pop    rbp
   0x00000000000006b6 <+44>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

so basically it gives me a set pattern of the execution, so i think that should mean the program should execute always in a particular order i tried disas main about 3 times to see if the order actually ever changes and it does not but when i finally run the binary that's generated it gives me different outputs

```
root@localhost:~/os/fork analysis# ./forkagain
LINUX
REDHAT
LINUX
REDHAT
REDHAT
REDHAT
root@localhost:~/os/fork analysis# ./forkagain
LINUX
LINUX
REDHAT
REDHAT
REDHAT
REDHAT
```

which is inconsistent to the observation that i made in the disas, can someone please fill up the gaps in my understanding?

[Fork Analysis Full](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1fd33ba28363b4f4f6c1499ca2cc8017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i tried disas main about 3 times to see if the order actually ever changes

The order is fixed at compile time, so it can *never* change without you recompiling the program.

In addition, the order is fixed by your program source -- the compiler is not allowed to re-order your output.

What you observe then is the indeterminism introduced by the OS as a result of calling `fork` -- after the `fork` there are no guarantees which process will run first, or for how long. The parent may run to completion, then the child. Or the child may run to completion first. Or they may both run with time-slicing, say one line at a time.

In addition, most non-ancient Linux systems today are running on multi-processor machines, and the two independent processes can run *simultaneously* after the fork.

An additional complication is that your program is not well-defined, because of stdio buffering. While you see 6 lines of output, it might be hard for you to explain this result:

```
./forkagain | wc -l
8
./forkagain > junk.out; cat junk.out
LINUX
REDHAT
LINUX
REDHAT
LINUX
REDHAT
LINUX
REDHAT
```

You should add `fflush(stdout);` before `fork` to avoid this complication.

P.S. You should also un-learn the bad habit of running as root -- sooner or later you'll make a stupid mistake (like typing `rm -rf *` in the wrong directory), and will be really sorry you did it as root.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the excellent input! so on the debugger multiprocessing is achieved, not sure where but on some blog i read that inside debuggers only single cores are used to observe the code flow easily...

Answer (score 2):

Each process executes in perfectly defined order. The trick here is that there is no guarantee of that each process will execute in one tick (the piece of time the process occupies the execution unit) and there is no guarantee of that two processes forked from the same process will get their tick in the order of forking.

If we assume that the printing of A (LINUX) and B (REDHAT) is the benchmark then you can get any sequence of As and Bs given that:

- sequence begins with A
- there are total of two As and four Bs
- there is are two Bs after each A

AABBBB
ABABBB
ABBABB

are all possible outputs on a preemptive multitasking OS.

P.S. And this answer is not complete without what Employed says.

Comment: A multi core cpu will have an option that after the fork both processes are concurrent

Comment: "are all possible outputs" -- other outputs are also possible -- see my answer.